# Checking a database in a Rails app to see if there are any new records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller, actionmailer

I have created a test Rails app (Rails v. 4.2.0) that is tied to an external API that has data from the US Congress.  I have a task that calls this API and pulls a list of all recently introduced bills in Congress.  I check the API once a day.

These bills are stored in the database with a Bill model that I've created.  Each bill is sponsored by a legislator.  The task that adds the bills to the database uses

```
Bill.find_or_create_by( <bill details> )
```

I have also created user accounts so that users can keep track of individual legislators by saving legislators to their favorites.  So I have a User model and Legislator model as well.

Diagram:

```
 User ---> Legislator followed by user ---> Bills sponsored by legislator
```

So, say a user is following Legislator X.  The next day, Legislator X is the sponsor on a newly created bill, so a new entry is added to the Bill table once the API is called.

I want to send an email to the user if any of their followed legislators sponsor new bills.  I am not sure how this should be done. How do I check the database to see if there are any new bills? For sending the emails out, should I somehow combine mailers with a scheduled task?

Comment: you can filter the bill by creation date and make a scheduled task running daily or by another period.

Answer (score 0):

Because you import the data with Rails tools you can use an [ActiveRecord Callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to send an e-mail.

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :send_mails

  private
    def send_mails
      self.legislator.followers.each do |follower|
        # trigger the email here
      end
    end
end
```